# how to custom tooltip in angular.nvd3 in tooltipContent

Tags: angular-nvd3

Here is my tooltip function

```
tooltipContent: function(label, value, elem, graph) { // jshint ignore:line 
   return  '<p>' + label + ' - ' + elem.value +'</p>';
},
```

and tooltip(android 5.1.1 - 40abc) is too far away from the pie.

[image]

Comment: Put some more details and if possible post your code in plnkr.co